# lambdas in removeIf

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, remove-if

```
HashSet<Integer> liczby = new HashSet<Integer>();
liczby.add(1);
liczby.add(2); 
liczby.add(3);
liczby.add(4);
liczby.removeIf ((Integer any) -> { return liczby.contains(3); });

for(Iterator<Integer> it = liczby.iterator(); it.hasNext();){
    Integer l2 = it.next();
    System.out.println(l2);
}
```

I can't understand why removeIf deletes not only 3 but also 1 and 2 condition should be satisfied only by 3...

Comment: I suggest to use only one language in your programs - English. Mixing language makes the code harder to read by other peers, if they do not know polish lang - and they do not have to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda is applied on each element and check if `3` is present, if yes it will delete the element :

```
1 -> 3 is present -> delete 1
2 -> 3 is present -> delete 2
3 -> 3 is present -> delete 3
4 -> 3 is not present -> don't delete 4
```

---

To remove all `3` element, you can use one of those solutions :

```
liczby.removeIf(any -> any.equals(3));
//-------------------------------------------------
liczby.removeIf(new Integer(3)::equals);
//-------------------------------------------------
Integer toRemove = 3;
liczby.removeIf(toRemove::equals);
```

---

---

**TIPS**

Your lambda can be simplified as :

```
liczby.removeIf(any -> liczby.contains(3));
```

For-each loop might be easier to use for simple iteration :

```
for(Integer i : liczby){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: *because it's primitive* no its not. :)

Comment: or just use `liczby.remove(3);`

Answer (score 6):

Think of it this way... as long as the set contains `3` it will keep removing hence the current outcome.

If you want to remove the `3` only then do this:

```
liczby.removeIf(e -> e == 3);
```

Comment: you could do a method reference also: `Integer interested = 3; liczby.removeIf(interested::equals);`